# Why am I in danger of being blocked?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Clarification added:  I have several questions.

1. Is it helpful to have unavailable deleted posts part of the score keeping?  How do we learn from this?  Also the criteria don't seem very clear.  Shouldn't they be?  (Ie the relative weights of deletions, down votes and up votes)
2. Google is directing some people seeking support to here.  Specifically for app engine / Python support.  Is it fair to treat such people in the same manner as others?   You can always tell  most people struggling with the SO 'culture' to just go away.  But that isn't so good for people sent here by Google.   Should there be more friendly/flexible standards for such queries?
   .......

I was about to post a question but I got the warning box that I'm in danger of being blocked.  I have so far asked nine questions, five with positive votes, two with zero, and two negatives (I made the mistake of assuming the question was obvious when stating a problem, I've learned to be more specific).

I understand those negatives (I think!) but my question is why is the threshold for being In danger of being blocked so low as 22% (based on number of questions, it's even lower of based on negative votes versus positives).

This is especially relevant right now as the question I need to ask is potentially going to be problematic, I wouldn't normally think of asking in SO as it is so restrictive  in its criteria, were it not for the fact that Google is now relyng on SO for community support for app engine - Python issues.

Comment: You have five deleted questions. Those count against you too.

Comment: How did you find that?  I went to questions on my profile and clicked deleted and it wouldn't show them.  I can't recall if these were questions I deletec or if someone 'kindly' did it for me.

Comment: No, the criteria should not be entirely clear simply because we don't want users to know that "this is sufficient to keep me just outside of a ban". You get a warning now, and that should suffice. Post good content and it should go away. And regarding point 2, the site's only responsibility is to uphold its own standards. What others tell you about the site or how you got here doesn't influence that. On rare occasions the team has contacted external parties who provided misleading information about the site's scope, but that doesn't happen too often it seems.

Comment: Of course deletions should count; otherwise users that *don't* learn can continue ad infinitum. The criteria are explicitly not disclosed because that'd enable cheating. The system could not possibly detect intent or why users have been coming to Stack Overflow, each and every one is given guidance on how to best use the site. There is even a checkbox to tick asking you to make sure to take those guidelines to heart. It is a pity many people *don't read these*.

Comment: I still havent managed to find my deleted posts, how do I do that (all I get is a msg saying "no recently deleted posts" or words to that effect).

Comment: A further question (Im trying to do the best I can on the app engine python questions I need to ask) - is it better to ask several short questions on one topic or combine them into one omnibus question.

Comment: _"is it better to ask several short questions on one topic or combine them into one omnibus question"_ To give you a quick answer to that: One question per post. If you have several questions about a project you're doing, start with the most pressing of the issues, or the one that seems to be the core issue. It might be that the answer to that actually helps solve your other issues. Don't post all the questions at once, and definitely do not post multiple questions on one question post. Your question will likely be closed as "Too Broad" if you do.